# How to set up proxy for Geoserver GetFeatureInfo call?

Tags: geoserver, web-mapping, leaflet, proxy, domains

I have problems with cross domain, I call GetFeatureInfo in Leaflet API. I was looking for solution and saw that proxy could solve that problem. Can you help me how to set it up? I have GeoServer run on Tomcat7 (Ubuntu).

Comment: the only difference between your question and any of the other proxy questions is that you are using leaflet and not openlayers. The solutions should all work for you as is.

Comment: It's not the same, OpenLayers has built in Proxy method, and Leaflet doesn't have!

Comment: I have no clue about Tomcat but if it is possible to manipulate files in the `GeoServer` directory, you could try the two steps described here: http://apps.csdila.ie.unimelb.edu.au/index.php/how-to-enable-cors-on-geoserver/ After adding those files, I had no more cross-domain issues when doing a `GetFeatureInfo` on a different `GeoServer` port than my webserver uses.